# Build PoDoFo on Windows MinGW

Tags: cmake, mingw, podofo

Hi I'm trying to compile PoDoFo 0.9.2 on Windows 7 with MinGW. I have successfully compiled *freetype2*, *OpenSSL* and *zlib*. Because i want to create a 64bit application a have to set MinGW x64 compilers to *cmake*. So I'm running *cmake* like this

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=c:/MinGW/x64/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_RANLIB=c:/MinGW/x64/bin/ranlib.exe -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=. -DPODOFO_NO_MULTITHREAD=TRUE -DCMAKE_RC_COMPILER=c:/MinGW/x64/bin/windres.exe -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=c:/MinGW/x64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=c:/MinGW/x64/bin/g++.exe -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=c:/MinGW/x64/include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=c:/MinGW/x64/lib -DPODOFO_BUILD_STATIC=TRUE ..
```

but I'm getting some unspecified error

```
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Syntax Warning in cmake code at

    C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0.9.2/CMakeLists.txt:144:36

  Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Syntax Warning in cmake code at

    C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0.9.2/CMakeLists.txt:145:45

  Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- Check for working C compiler: c:/MinGW/x64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: c:/MinGW/x64/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: c:/MinGW/x64/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: c:/MinGW/x64/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
WANT_LIB64 unset; assuming normal library directory names
Will install libraries to C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0.9.2/build/lib
-- Looking for strings.h
-- Looking for strings.h - found
-- Looking for arpa/inet.h
-- Looking for arpa/inet.h - not found
-- Looking for winsock2.h
-- Looking for winsock2.h - found
-- Looking for mem.h
-- Looking for mem.h - found
-- Looking for ctype.h
-- Looking for ctype.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for BaseTsd.h
-- Looking for BaseTsd.h - found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
Both PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED and PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC set
  so disabling shared library generation (win32)
Using gcc specific compiler options
Have gcc 4.x
-- Found ZLIB: C:/Program Files/TortoiseGit/bin/zlib1.dll
Found zlib headers in c:/MinGW/x64/include, library at C:/Program Files/Tortoise
Git/bin/zlib1.dll
-- Found LIBCRYPTO: c:/MinGW/x64/lib/libcrypto.a
Found OpenSSL's libCrypto headers in c:/MinGW/x64/include, library at c:/MinGW/x
64/lib/libcrypto.a
-- Could NOT find LIBIDN (missing:  LIBIDN_LIBRARY LIBIDN_INCLUDE_DIR)
Libidn not found. AES-256 Encryption support will be disabled
-- Could NOT find LIBJPEG (missing:  LIBJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR)
libjpeg not found: Library c:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/jpeg.dll, headers LIBJ
PEG_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
Libjpeg not found. JPEG support will be disabled
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR)
Libtiff not found. TIFF support will be disabled
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/
FindPNG.cmake:34 (find_package):
  File C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPNG.cmake
  includes C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0.9.2/cmake/modules/FindZLIB.cmake
  (found via CMAKE_MODULE_PATH) which shadows C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake
  2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake.  This may cause errors later on
  .

  Policy CMP0017 is not set: Prefer files from the CMake module directory
  when including from there.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0017" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:349 (FIND_PACKAGE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find PNG (missing:  PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR)
LibPng not found. PNG support will be disabled
-- Ensure you cppunit installed version is at least 1.12.0
Cppunit not found. No unit tests will be built.
-- Found OpenSSL: c:/MinGW/x64/lib/libssl.a
Found freetype library at c:/MinGW/x64/lib/libfreetype.dll.a, headers c:/MinGW/x
64/include;c:/MinGW/x64/include
-- Could NOT find Fontconfig (missing:  FONTCONFIG_LIBRARIES FONTCONFIG_INCLUDE_
DIR)
-- Could NOT find Lua50 (missing:  LUA_LIBRARIES LUA_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find Lua (missing:  LUA_LIBRARIES LUA_INCLUDE_DIR)
Lua not found - PoDoFoImpose and PoDoFoColor will be built without Lua support
Building non multithreaded version of PoDoFo.
Building static PoDoFo library
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set
to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake file
s:
PNG_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "podofo_static" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podof
o-0.9.2/src
    linked by target "ContentParser" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podof
o-0.9.2/test/ContentParser
    linked by target "ContentParser" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podof
o-0.9.2/test/ContentParser
    linked by target "CreationTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo
-0.9.2/test/CreationTest
    linked by target "CreationTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo
-0.9.2/test/CreationTest
    linked by target "DeviceTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0
.9.2/test/DeviceTest
    linked by target "DeviceTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0
.9.2/test/DeviceTest
    linked by target "FilterTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0
.9.2/test/FilterTest
    linked by target "FilterTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0
.9.2/test/FilterTest
    linked by target "FormTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0.9
.2/test/FormTest
    linked by target "FormTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0.9
.2/test/FormTest
    linked by target "ObjectParserTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/po
dofo-0.9.2/test/ObjectParserTest
    linked by target "ObjectParserTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/po
dofo-0.9.2/test/ObjectParserTest
    linked by target "ParserTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0
.9.2/test/ParserTest
    linked by target "SignatureTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podof
o-0.9.2/test/SignatureTest
    linked by target "SignatureTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podof
o-0.9.2/test/SignatureTest
    linked by target "TokenizerTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podof
o-0.9.2/test/TokenizerTest
    linked by target "TokenizerTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podof
o-0.9.2/test/TokenizerTest
    linked by target "VariantTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-
0.9.2/test/VariantTest
    linked by target "VariantTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-
0.9.2/test/VariantTest
    linked by target "WatermarkTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podof
o-0.9.2/test/WatermarkTest
    linked by target "WatermarkTest" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podof
o-0.9.2/test/WatermarkTest
    linked by target "podofobox" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0.
9.2/tools/podofobox
    linked by target "podofocolor" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-
0.9.2/tools/podofocolor
    linked by target "podofocountpages" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/po
dofo-0.9.2/tools/podofocountpages
    linked by target "podofocrop" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0
.9.2/tools/podofocrop
    linked by target "podofoencrypt" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podof
o-0.9.2/tools/podofoencrypt
    linked by target "podofogc" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0.9
.2/tools/podofogc
    linked by target "podofoimgextract" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/po
dofo-0.9.2/tools/podofoimgextract
    linked by target "podofoimg2pdf" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podof
o-0.9.2/tools/podofoimg2pdf
    linked by target "podofomerge" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-
0.9.2/tools/podofomerge
    linked by target "podofopages" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-
0.9.2/tools/podofopages
    linked by target "podofopdfinfo" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podof
o-0.9.2/tools/podofopdfinfo
    linked by target "podofotxt2pdf" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podof
o-0.9.2/tools/podofotxt2pdf
    linked by target "podofotxtextract" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/po
dofo-0.9.2/tools/podofotxtextract
    linked by target "podofouncompress" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/po
dofo-0.9.2/tools/podofouncompress
    linked by target "podofoimpose" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo
-0.9.2/tools/podofoimpose
    linked by target "podofoincrementalupdates" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Down
loads/podofo-0.9.2/tools/podofoincrementalupdates
    linked by target "podofoxmp" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0.
9.2/tools/podofoxmp
    linked by target "helloworld" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0
.9.2/examples/helloworld
    linked by target "helloworld-base14" in directory C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/p
odofo-0.9.2/examples/helloworld-base14

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0.9.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log
".
See also "C:/Users/Honza/Downloads/podofo-0.9.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log"
.
```

CMakeOutput.log conatins this http://pastebin.com/tBr5G4Mr

CMakeError.log contains this http://pastebin.com/rdYMFfKr

Comment: It seems that PNG is still required for some parts of the build while it will be disabled in other.

Comment: Yes CMake requires PNG library, but it's CMake bug. I removed PNG check from CMakeLists.txt and successfully created Makefile. But build stops at 65% at windres.exe unkonwn option -- W. I've found it's CMake bug in versions later than 2.8.3. I've installed CMake 2.8.3 and everything is working fine now and I have my libpodofo.a :)

Answer (score -1):

I's a bug in CMake or in CMakeLists.txt. I've installed CMake 2.8.3 (peviously I have 2.8.12) and everything is working now.

Comment: I would call this a bug in the CMakeLists.txt for PoDoFo. You probably should inform the developers that although the CMakeLists.txt allows usage without PNG for some parts it ignores that in other parts of the CMakeLists.txt.