# Configuring PoDoFo in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, pdf-generation, cmake-gui, podofo

The [PoDoFo requirement Page](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/about.html#requ) says that `zlib` and `freetype2` are mandotory libraries and rest are optional.

I have already built the `zlib` and `freetype2` and provided their path to CMake GUI.

When I try to **Configure** PoDoFo in CMake, I get a whole bunch of errors as following:

```
WANT_LIB64 unset; assuming normal library directory names
Will install libraries to C:/Program Files (x86)/PoDoFo/lib
WARNING: ZLIB debug library will be used even for release builds
Found zlib headers in C:/softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/zlib128, library at C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/zlib128/BUILD/Debug/zlibstaticd.lib
Could NOT find LIBCRYPTO (missing: LIBCRYPTO_LIBRARY LIBCRYPTO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
OpenSSL's libCrypto not found. Encryption support will be disabled
Could NOT find LIBIDN (missing: LIBIDN_LIBRARY LIBIDN_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Libidn not found. AES-256 Encryption support will be disabled
Could NOT find LIBJPEG (missing: LIBJPEG_LIBRARY LIBJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
libjpeg not found: Library LIBJPEG_LIBRARY_RELEASE-NOTFOUND, headers LIBJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
Libjpeg not found. JPEG support will be disabled
Could NOT find TIFF (missing: TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Libtiff not found. TIFF support will be disabled
Could NOT find PNG (missing: PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
LibPng not found. PNG support will be disabled
Ensure you cppunit installed version is at least 1.12.0
Cppunit not found. No unit tests will be built.
OpenSSL: Could not find the debug and release version of openssl
OpenSSL: Disabling OpenSSL
WARNING: FREETYPE debug library will be used even for release builds
Found freetype library at C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/FreeType/GnuWin32/lib/freetype.lib, headers C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/FreeType/GnuWin32/include
Could NOT find Fontconfig (missing: FONTCONFIG_LIBRARIES FONTCONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find Lua50 (missing: LUA_LIBRARIES LUA_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find Lua (missing: LUA_LIBRARIES LUA_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Lua not found - PoDoFoImpose and PoDoFoColor will be built without Lua support
Building multithreaded version of PoDoFo.
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - not found
Found Threads: TRUE 
Building static PoDoFo library
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
PNG_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
linked by target "podofo_static" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/src
linked by target "ContentParser" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/ContentParser
linked by target "ContentParser" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/ContentParser
linked by target "CreationTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/CreationTest
linked by target "CreationTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/CreationTest
linked by target "FilterTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/FilterTest
linked by target "FilterTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/FilterTest
linked by target "FormTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/FormTest
linked by target "FormTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/FormTest
linked by target "ObjectParserTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/ObjectParserTest
linked by target "ObjectParserTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/ObjectParserTest
linked by target "ParserTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/ParserTest
linked by target "SignatureTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/SignatureTest
linked by target "SignatureTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/SignatureTest
linked by target "TokenizerTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/TokenizerTest
linked by target "TokenizerTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/TokenizerTest
linked by target "VariantTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/VariantTest
linked by target "VariantTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/VariantTest
linked by target "WatermarkTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/WatermarkTest
linked by target "WatermarkTest" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/test/WatermarkTest
linked by target "podofobox" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofobox
linked by target "podofocolor" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofocolor
linked by target "podofocountpages" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofocountpages
linked by target "podofocrop" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofocrop
linked by target "podofoencrypt" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofoencrypt
linked by target "podofogc" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofogc
linked by target "podofoimgextract" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofoimgextract
linked by target "podofoimg2pdf" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofoimg2pdf
linked by target "podofomerge" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofomerge
linked by target "podofopages" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofopages
linked by target "podofopdfinfo" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofopdfinfo
linked by target "podofotxt2pdf" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofotxt2pdf
linked by target "podofotxtextract" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofotxtextract
linked by target "podofouncompress" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofouncompress
linked by target "podofoimpose" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofoimpose
linked by target "podofoincrementalupdates" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofoincrementalupdates
linked by target "podofoxmp" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/tools/podofoxmp
linked by target "helloworld" in directory C:/Siddrth/softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/examples/helloworld
linked by target "helloworld-base14" in directory C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/examples/helloworld-base14
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/BUILD/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C: /softwares/4_PoDoFoPdfGeneration/podofo094/BUILD/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: This question has already been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221700/build-podofo-on-windows-mingw), although the answer is not satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have only one error:

> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but
>   they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set
>   and tested correctly in the CMake files: PNG_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)

You have to install/build libpng library if you haven't already, and among the advanced variable of cmake_gui you must set the path to it.

Comment: But as per the requirement page of PoDoFo, `libpng` library is optional...isn't it?

Comment: @skm I don't know PoDoFo, I am only trying to help you interpreting cmake output, which seemingly say you should have `PNG_LIBRARY` variable set. From cmake-gui, try to put a variable search "PNG", there might be an option to disable the dependency. BTW, which cmake version do you have? (I ask because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221700/build-podofo-on-windows-mingw))

Comment: @skm It's probably also enough to set PNG_LIBRARY variable to an empty value, if you have access to it from `cmake-gui`.